# Como mudar as paginas de um site no celular arrastando o dedo na touch screen para direita ou esquerda utilizando javascript

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como posso utilizar javascript para realizar a mudança de pagina na tela de toque do celular, de forma que arrastando para esquerda vá para pagina anterior e para direita para próxima pagina.

Atualmente eu tenho esse código abaixo que utiliza as teclas de seta do teclado, gostaria de saber como posso complementar esse código com essa função adicional.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.onkeydown = arrowChecker;

function arrowChecker(e) {  
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == "37") { //left
        document.location.href = "/'.$UrlArray1.'/'.$UrlArray2.'/?leitor=fullpg10&paginainicial='.($inicioA).'&paginafinal='.($fimA).'&#iniciopg";
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == "39") { //right
       document.location.href = "/'.$UrlArray1.'/'.$UrlArray2.'/?leitor=fullpg10&paginainicial='.($fim+1).'&paginafinal='.($fim+10).'&#iniciopg";
    }
}
 </script>
```

Comment: isso ajuda? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34149/como-determinar-a-dire%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-touchmove  só adaptar para chamar as functions que já tem

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu queria obrigado.